# What is the meaning of the symbols on the Stormtrooper's left pauldron?

Tags: star-wars, object-identification

I found a website that purports to show errors in popular movies. That is only marginally interesting to me. However, the picture on the front page (from a Star Wars movie) has me intrigued.

[image: Storm Trooper]

I am curious about the markings on the Storm Trooper's left shoulder.

I recognize that the symbol is similar to the Galactic Empire insignia

[image: Insignia]

but I can't identify the two other markings. Are there other pictures of Storm Troopers with the same or similar markings? Do they have any particular meaning?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The symbols are characters in [Aurebesh](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aurebesh), the *Star Wars* alphabet. Aurebesh is based on simple character substitution, so it's easy to tell you that those are the characters for "UK."

Less easy is what that actually *means*. Best I can tell, this is a kind of identifier for the [United Kingdom branch](http://www.ukgarrison.co.uk/) of the [501st Legion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/501st_Legion), an organization of enthusiastic cosplayers. I've found this discussed on [one of the club's forums](http://www.whitearmor.net/forum/topic/16368-symbols-on-armor/), where you can see the decal being applied to members' armour (click to embiggen):

[image]

[image]

As far as I know, no members of the 501st have appeared in armour in any *Star Wars* film. If forced to guess, I would assume that whoever composited that image borrowed a publicity shot from the UK Garrison, possibly without realizing that it wasn't an official image; film-accurate costumes is one of the 501st's goals.

This decal seems to be highly non-standard, even among other branches of the 501st; based on the discussion in that forum thread I linked to, the 501st generally disallows "non-canon" markings at formal appearances. UKG appears to be an exception, though I'm not familiar enough with the club's internal politics to speculate on why.

Comment: Fascinating! So the fact that the insignia looks like a 6 pointed star and those letters happen to be identical to Hebrew letters which would have a value of 29 is completely coincidence? Neat! Thanks.

Comment: @Danno *Probably* a coincidence. Aurebesh is, of course, a completely designed alphabet, so it's not impossible that it was inspired by Hebrew. But there's no significance to "29" in this context, no

Comment: This is in fact the brand for the UK Garrison of the 501st Legion a group of costumers not cosplayers, and some of them were in a Star Wars movie having appeared as Stormtroopers in The Force Awakens

Comment: @Baz the storm trooper design in OP image was *not* in the Force Awakens

Comment: The 501st Legion can be hired to appear, in costume, at events or other gatherings.  Yes; not cosplayers per se.